# LINQ query to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Please anyone assist me with the MySQL query equivalent of the below LINQ

```
var orders = _dbContext.Orders.Where(order => order.Id == orderId)
                   .Include(order => order.OrderDetails);
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = @id ORDER BY order_details`?

Comment: Isn't that just `SELECT OrderDetails FROM orders WHERE Id = 'orderId';`, where you'd need to substitute the `orderId` variable?

Comment: There is no equivalent. SQL doesn't return objects with nested objects. I don't understand the question, you can simply check the generated SQL, but that's not an equivalent, it's the mere *means* to get the data that construct the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions about the names of the tables and the primary and foreign keys, the SQL would look something like this.

```
select order.*, order_detail.* 
from order 
inner join order_detail 
on order.id = order_detail.order_id
where order.id = @order_id
```

Comment: You're welcome. Looking at it again, though, I should probably have said left join instead of inner join because an inner join would exclude orders with no associated detail rows.